# Why is postgres not respecting the configs passes via config file?

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to change postgres settings using the /var/lib/pgsql/12/data/postgresql file.
Specifically the settings wal_level to miniaml or max_wal_senders to 10 in order to restart a broken postgres service, however even after changing the config file, it still outputs the same error message : " WAL streaming (max_wal_senders > 0) requires wal_level "replica" or "logical" "

Comment: 'minimal' is what you are trying to change it to, or change it from?

Comment: Did you un-comment the setting? To your question add the actual setting from `postgresql.conf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone runs into a similar issue, the problem was that i initially changed the config from logical to minimal, however seems like performing that change doesnt alter the dependency max_wal_senders to minimal. Upon restarting postgres, the wal_level = minimal is set on an autoconfig file that runs upon start up which will conflict with  the "max_wal_senders " on the normal config file. In order to run it we changed the autoconfig file to logical and postgres ran again

Comment: any more info on how to actually change that file and where is the auto config file?